# ajax listener in composite component stops working when I add clientBehavior

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I have this composite component and it works perfectly.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="listenerController" ... />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:outputPanel id="selectOnePanel">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOne" ... >
            <f:selectItems ... />
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{listenerController.listenerMethod()}" ... />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:outputPanel>
</cc:implementation>
```

But I wanted to listen to the "change" event from outside this component. So I used the "cc:clientBehavior" in the cc:interface. For the purpose of testing I added a couple of "console.out"s.

First I updated the composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
     <cc:attribute name="listenerController" ... />
     <cc::clientBehavior name="change" targets="#{cc.clientId}":selectOne" event="change" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:outputPanel id="selectOnePanel">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOne" ... >
            <f:selectItems ... />
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{listenerController.listenerMethod()} 
                    onstart="console.log(1);" oncomplete="console.log(2); ... />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:outputPanel>
</cc:implementation>
```

And how I would use it:

```
<xx:compostiteComponentName>
    <p:ajax event="change" onstart="console.log(3)"; oncomplete="console.log(4);" />
</xx:compostiteComponentName>
```

The problem is that the listener in the composite component stops working. All the "onstart"s and "oncomplete"s seem to work, since the console output is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Why does the listener stop working?

Comment: Tried if this works with a plain non-primefaces jsf counterpart (so the `h:selectOneMenu` and `f:ajax`). That way you can narrow down if it is PrimeFaces related or plain jsf)

Answer (score 0):

1-Composite components targets just local components so no #{cc.id}:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="listenerController" ... />
    <cc::clientBehavior name="change" targets="selectOne" event="change" />
</cc:interface>
```

2- Don't forget to inform the listener on the usage of composite:

```
<xx:compostiteComponentName>
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{listenerController.listenerMethod()} 
                onstart="console.log(3);" oncomplete="console.log(4); ... />
</xx:compostiteComponentName>
```

3 - You may want to remove the ajax event on the selectOneMenu, because when you especify a ajax behavior on the composite, it is attached to the target component and it will not replace the existings ones, wich means that leaving that way the listener will be called two times.

Comment: Sure about 3? You cannot add two ajax handlers for the same event directly on the component afaik (but that might be related not not two different listeners, not sure about identical ones)

Comment: Sure, because I tested the code and the listener method was called two times.